# Is there any performance cost in using runtime.Caller?

Tags: performance, logging, go, runtime

I'm using [runtime.Caller](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Caller) quite extensively in my app (for loggin purposes) and was curious as if there is any big performance issue because of it.

Also, as far as I know, its the same api that the std lib log package uses if Lshortfile or Llongfile [flags](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#pkg-constants) are set.

Comment: Of course there's a cost, it's just whether it matters for you. If you think it's causing a performance problem, profile and measure.

Comment: I'd  put runtime.Caller either behind a debug/logging flag or at least defer its call. It obviously has a big performance cost since it does some code introspection.

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/tlog.app/go/loc is 3 times faster than runtime.caller.